# Will Mac Mini 2011 run two HD monitors?

Tags: display, mac-mini

I'm thinking of getting the basic Mac mini with the Intel HD 3000 graphics. I'm planning to run two 1920x1080 screens - one with a mini DisplayPort to DVI, the other with an HDMI to DVI.

Has anyone tried this and confirmed that it works?

I've seen many threads talking about using two monitors, but the resolution hasn't been specified.

The tech specs page says:

- Thunderbolt port with support for up to 2560-by-1600 resolution
- HDMI port with support for up to 1920-by-1200 resolution
- DVI output using HDMI to DVI Adapter (included)
- Support for dual display and video mirroring

I'm not clear whether that means that I can run on monitor from the mini DisplayPort and one from the HDMI, or whether the resolution is capped somehow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It *is* able to do so, I'm doing this exact thing right now. I've got two 1080p monitors connected, one via HDMI (to DVI), one via Thunderbolt (also to DVI) - works all fine :-)

Comment: Me too now! :) It's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to. 1080p isn't all that high of a resolution these days, and the HD3000 is perfectly capable of driving two displays.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently running a HP Pavilion 32-inch (2560 x 1440) and an Acer S232HL 23-inch (1920 x 1080) on a Mac mini (Late 2012) with Intel HD Graphics 4000 1536 MB

I am using a DisplayPort to DisplayPort Cable, Mini DP to DP for the Pavilion and it's perfect.

I am using hdmi to hdmi currently on the Acer, but am unable to get the 1920 with that  (max 1600 x 900). But it's an old monitor(2010) so I may think about replacing it as there are no controls on it to adjust width or height.